# My Python program is very slow! How can I speed it up? Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: python, performance

EDIT: I ran the python profiler and the two most time-consuming things (this is after I decided to comment out the webbrowser portion and Firefox portion of the code, because I knew they were going to be the slowest part...) , the slowest part of my program is `re.findall` and `re.compile` and also (len) and (append to list).

I don't know if I should post all of my code on here at once because I worked really hard on my program (even if it isn't too good), so for now I'm just going to ask...How do I make my Python program faster?

I have 3 suspects right now for it being so slow:

1. Maybe my computer is just slow
2. Maybe my internet is too slow (sometimes my program has to download the html of web pages and then it searches through the html for a specific piece of text)
3. My code is slow (too many loops maybe? something else? I'm new to this so I wouldn't know!)

If anyone could offer me advice, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

EDIT:

My code uses lots of loops I think...also, another thing is that for the program to work you have to be logged in to this website: http://www.locationary.com/

```
from urllib import urlopen
from gzip import GzipFile
from cStringIO import StringIO
import re
import urllib
import urllib2
import webbrowser
import time
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import os

def download(url):
    s = urlopen(url).read()
    if s[:2] == '\x1f\x8b': # assume it's gzipped data
        with GzipFile(mode='rb', fileobj=StringIO(s)) as ifh:
            s = ifh.read()
    return s

for t in range(3,39):
    print t
    s = download('http://www.locationary.com/place/en/US/Utah/Provo-page' + str(t) + '/?ACTION_TOKEN=NumericAction')
    findLoc = re.compile('http://www\.locationary\.com/place/en/US/.{1,50}/.{1,50}/.{1,100}\.jsp')
    findLocL = re.findall(findLoc,s)
    W = []
    X = []
    XA = []
    Y = []
    YA = []
    Z = []
    ZA = []

    for i in range(0,25):
        b = download(findLocL[i])        
        findYP = re.compile('http://www\.yellowpages\.com/')
        findYPL = re.findall(findYP,b)
        findTitle = re.compile('<title>(.*) \(\d{1,10}.{1,100}\)</title>')
        getTitle = re.findall(findTitle,b)        
        findAddress = re.compile('<title>.{1,100}\((.*), .{4,14}, United States\)</title>')
        getAddress = re.findall(findAddress,b)        
        if not findYPL:
            if not getTitle:
                print ""
            else:
                W.append(findLocL[i])
            b = download(findLocL[i])
            if not getTitle:
                print ""
            else:
                X.append(getAddress)
            b = download(findLocL[i])
            if not getTitle:
                print ""
            else:
                Y.append(getTitle)
    sizeWXY = len(W)

    def XReplace(text, dic):
        for i, j in dic.iteritems():
            text = text.replace(i, j)  
        XA.append(text)

    def YReplace(text2, dic2):
        for k, l in dic2.iteritems():
            text2 = text2.replace(k, l)  
        YA.append(text2)

    for d in range(0,sizeWXY):
        old = str(X[d])
        reps = {' ':'-', ',':'', '\'':'', '[':'', ']':''}
        XReplace(old, reps)
        old2 = str(Y[d])
        YReplace(old2, reps)

    count = 0    
    for e in range(0,sizeWXY):
        newYPL = "http://www.yellowpages.com/" + XA[e] + "/" + YA[e] + "?order=distance"
        v = download(newYPL)
        abc = str('<h3 class="business-name fn org">\n<a href="')
        dfe = str('" class="no-tracks url "')
        findFinal = re.compile(abc + '(.*)' + dfe)
        getFinal = re.findall(findFinal, v)
        if not getFinal:
            W.remove(W[(e-count)])
            X.remove(X[(e-count)])
            count = (count+1)
        else:
            for f in range(0,1):
                Z.append(getFinal[f])
    XA = []
    for c in range(0,(len(X))):
        aGd = re.compile('(.*), .{1,50}')
        bGd = re.findall(aGd, str(X[c]))
        XA.append(bGd)
    LenZ = len(Z)
    V = []
    for i in range(0,(len(W))):
        if i == 0:
            countTwo = 0
        gda = download(Z[i-(countTwo)])
        ab = str('"street-address">\n')
        cd = str('\n</span>')
        ZAddress = re.compile(ab + '(.*)' + cd)
        ZAddress2 = re.findall(ZAddress, gda)
        for b in range(0,(len(ZAddress2))):
            if not ZAddress2[b]:
                print ""
            else:
                V.append(str(ZAddress2[b]))
                a = str(W[i-(countTwo)])
                n = str(Z[i-(countTwo)])
                c = str(XA[i])
                d = str(V[i])
                #webbrowser.open(a)
                #webbrowser.open(n)
                m = SequenceMatcher(None, c, d)
                if m.ratio() < 0.50:
                    Z.remove(Z[i-(countTwo)])
                    W.remove(W[i-(countTwo)])
                    countTwo = (countTwo+1)

    def ZReplace(text3, dic3):
        for p, q in dic3.iteritems():
            text3 = text3.replace(p, q)  
        ZA.append(text3)

    for y in range(0,len(Z)):
        old3 = str(Z[y])
        reps2 = {':':'%3A', '/':'%2F', '?':'%3F', '=':'%3D'}
        ZReplace(old3, reps2)
    for z in range(0,len(ZA)):
        findPID = re.compile('\d{5,20}')
        getPID = re.findall(findPID,str(W[z]))
        newPID = re.sub("\D", "", str(getPID))
        finalURL = "http://www.locationary.com/access/proxy.jsp?ACTION_TOKEN=proxy_jsp$JspView$SaveAction&inPlaceID=" + str(newPID) + "&xxx_c_1_f_987=" + str(ZA[z])
        webbrowser.open(finalURL)
        time.sleep(5)

    os.system("taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe")
```

Comment: Quite hard to answer without seeing your code.

Comment: "I don't know if I should post all of my code on here at once because I worked really hard on my program"  What?

Comment: Maybe you should ask this on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) more than on StackOverflow, as SO is mainly for people having problems with a piece of code, and it seems your program works, it's just slow. (Also, as @SebastianPaaskeTørholm told, it's quite hard to help without any code)

Comment: how do you put code in your question??

Comment: You should remove commented code (it reveals to others bits of hidden information on the way you are structuring your final product)

Comment: "THIS IS AFTER..." Please do NOT write in ALL CAPITALS.  It's RUDE and LOOKS LIKE YOU'RE SHOUTING.  Please edit your question to remove the ALL CAPS.  Also, please remove the "Edit:" stuff.  Please format your question to be one, coherent question so people can read and understand it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The first thing to do when a program is slow is to **identify bottlenecks**; in fact, you want to optimize things that take a long time, not things that may actually be fast.  In Python, the most efficient way to do this is with **one of the [Python profilers](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html)**, which are dedicated tools for performance analysis.  Here is a quickstart:

```
python -m cProfile -o prof.dat <prog> <args>
```

runs your program and stores profiling information in prof.dat.  Then,

```
python -m pstats prof.dat
```

runs the **profiling information analysis tool** pstats.  Important pstat commands include:

```
sort time
```

which sorts functions by the time spent in them, and which you can use with a different key instead of `time` (`cumulative`,…). Another important command is

```
stats
```

which print statistics (or `stats 10` to print the first 10 most time-consuming functions).  You can obtain help with `?`, or `help <command>`.

The way to optimize your program then consists in dealing with the particular code that causes the bottlenecks.  You can post the timing results and maybe get some more specific help on the sections of the program that could be most usefully optimized.

Comment: I tried it. The slowest things were "re.findall" "re.compile" "len (object)" and "append" to list

Comment: @jacob501: For `re.compile`, you can put the compilations *outside of the loops*.  Another thing that you might contemplate is to split your code into various functions: the profiler times individual functions; by splitting your code into functions, you can therefore obtaine more detailed information about which part of your code should be optimized (where are the `findall()` functions that use most of the time? etc.).  You can then think about how to optimize that part (and maybe ask a specific question about this on StackOverflow or Code Review on StackExchange).

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start would be in identifying places where the code has to perform many iterations (nested for loops, for example) or process large amounts of data. Place print statements before and after these and you'll be able to determine if that's what's taking ages. Then you can look at why.

Or, if it's a small program, just post the entire thing.